# Does SQLite's VACUUM preserve key relations?

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, rdbms

[`PRAGMA foreign_keys`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) is enabled.

Table `foo` has no explicit `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Table `bar` has `foo_rowid INTEGER` with `FOREIGN KEY (foo_rowid) REFERENCES foo(rowid)`.

Row *f* in `foo` has a `rowid` of *x* and row *b* in `bar` has a `foo_rowid` of *x*.

**If [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) changes *f*'s `rowid` to *y*, does it change *b*'s `foo_rowid` to *y*?**

> The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible because [a rowid cannot be referenced by another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002306/972499). If a column can be referenced by a foreign key, it cannot be changed by `VACUUM`.

Comment: You can indeed reference a rowid in a foreign key constraint. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not for non-primary key `rowid`. Lets create table without primary key:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43
sqlite> create table test(name varchar(20));
sqlite> insert into test values('a'),('b'),('c');
sqlite> select rowid,* from test;
1|a
2|b
3|c
```

So far so good. Let's delete something:

```
sqlite> delete from test where rowid=2;
sqlite> select rowid,* from test;
1|a
3|c
```

Wow, rowid was kept - this is promising! However, what happens after VACUUM?

```
sqlite> vacuum full;
sqlite> select rowid,* from test;
1|a
2|c
sqlite>
```

Oops, it got renumbered!

In other words, you must create true auto-increment column for this to work and keep your ids intact after VACUUM.

Comment: This answer only shows that `VACUUM` can change `rowid`s; my question is: _if that happens_, does it change foreign keys to match?

Comment: Does this imply that if I create a **non auto-increment** primary key integer column then the values in that column can still be changed after a `vacuum` operation?

Comment: No, any physical column (one that you defined as part of your CREATE TABLE statement) cannot be changed by vacuum.