# Why does referencing a SQLite rowid cause foreign key mismatch?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database

```
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(name);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE bar(foo_rowid REFERENCES foo(rowid));
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES('baz');
sqlite> SELECT rowid, name FROM foo;
1|baz
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar (foo_rowid) VALUES (1);
Error: foreign key mismatch
```

Why does this error occur? It is a [DML error](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes), but I don't know what's wrong because:

- `foo` exists.
- `foo.rowid` exists.
- `foo.rowid` is the primary key of `foo` and therefore constrained to uniqueness.
- `bar.foo_rowid` is one column, which matches the fact that `foo.rowid` is one column.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SQLite documentation is quite clear on foreign keys:

```
The parent key must be a named column or columns in the parent table, not the rowid.
```

(See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).)

You can't use `rowid` for this, so just define your own auto incrementing primary key for the table.

Comment: And it's even possible to name that PK `rowid`.

Comment: I have an error saying: _foreign key mismatch - "child_table" referencing "parent_table"_ . I did what u said but still not working ..

Comment: On the other hand, `If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID.` from https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 8):

You can not use rowid if not defined in your table, but if you define it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clase(
ROWID INTEGER NOT NULL,
nombre  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ROWID));
```

The ROWID column can be used to make foreign references, and when you insert a record into the table, the ROWID column behaves like an autoincrement field, it is why that sqlite recommended don't have autoincrement fields.

Note: The ROWID column can be called otherwise only it has to be of type INTEGER and primary key of the table.